# Resetting default fonts/colours for plots in Python/Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, colors

First time here and newbie so please bear with me.

I'm following along a data viz tutorial with matplotlib. I'm getting the same results (go me) but the font used (in the plot legend in particular) and the default co lours are different and no parameter has been set to change them. And of course the tutorial's stuff looks much nicer. I don't know why this happens but I'm thinking that maybe I did change some of the stuff in unrelated notebooks and those choices stuck. If so, how do I "reset" please?

I am not allowed to attach screenshots yet. Basically, my plot lines are light blue and orange while his are the traditional discrete dark blue and green. My legend font looks like bad excel while his looks like LateX.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: It's really hard to know what problem you face without seeing any pictures. So if you have a link to the tutorial, please share it; also you *can* attach pictures, they will be shown as link in your case.

Comment: When you first join, you can't post screenshot. The tutorial is offline (and large). I will post screenshots when allowed, though I think one answer below is giving me some clues. Thanks a lot for reading me and answering. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find all the built in matplotlib themes, use

```
plt.style.available
```

I think the normal one is 'default'. So add this before you make your plots:

```
plt.style.use(['default'])
```

But you can make your plots look even better than the tutorial by using some of the other ones.

Comment: HI Liam,I just tried it and I think you nailed it,The default mode is classsic. Running that gives me at match except that the plot now has a grey background (it doesn't in the tutorial). But the line colours and the legend font now match which is brilliant. So it sounds to me that the tutorial uses a custolmised version of of classic with no plot background (and it looks much better for it). Now that I know what to look for, I'll go learn how to customise styles. Thank you very much for getting in touch and helping out. Much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways you can do this and they vary depending on the specific use case but the one I use most often is

```py
from matplotlib import rcParams, rcParamsDefault
rcParams.update(rcParamsDefault)
```

Although it is likely the case that the tutorial is using a style other than the default so I wouldn't necessarily expect this to make your output look exactly like the tutorial. When using LaTex with matplotlib I use

```py
pgf_with_latex = {
    "text.usetex": True,
    "pgf.rcfonts": False,
    "pgf.preamble": [
        r'\usepackage{color}'
    ]
}

rcParams.update(pgf_with_latex)
```

You can find more information [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) regarding customization and [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/usetex.html) regarding using LaTex with matplotlib.

Comment: Thank you William. I am starting with the style sheet route. LaTeX is somewhat beyond me, but I will try the RC params too, I id create a new style sheet based on classic? I out in the stylelib dir created in my .matplotlib config dir....but it refuses to find it. 2am here so I'll post again tomorrow. Thanks again all.